# How to determine the existence of encryption headers?

Tags: java, encryption, unzip, zip

According to the [.ZIP File Format Specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) (dated September 1, 2012), the overall .ZIP file format is as follows:

> [local file header 1]
>   [encryption header 1]
>   [file data 1]
>   [data descriptor 1]
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   [local file header n]
>   [encryption header n]
>   [file data n]
>   [data descriptor n]
>   [archive decryption header]
>   [archive extra data record]
>   [central directory header 1]
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   [central directory header n]
>   [zip64 end of central directory record]
>   [zip64 end of central directory locator]
>   [end of central directory record]

I'm able to determine the presence/position of local file headers, central directory headers and the end of central directory record by means of the respective signatures.

How can I determine the existence or not of the encryption headers? Specifically, I want to know, for any given file with my zip, whether the file data immediately follows the local file header or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 4.4.4 of the specification explains it:

> 4.4.4 general purpose bit flag: (2 bytes)
>
> ```
>    Bit 0: If set, indicates that the file is encrypted.
> ```

Therefore, and given that the encryption header has a fixed size, you know what to do ;)

Comment: Awesome! Just to confirm, is bit 0 the left-most bit or the right-most bit?

Comment: Left-most. Glad I could help ;)

Comment: Thank you so so so much. You've been a huge help! I was looking at that document for a while and starting to wane.

Comment: fge, I just run some tests and it looks like bit 0 is the least significant bit, i.e. the right-most bit of the least significant byte.

Comment: Huh, that is strange... But to be honest I didn't read the whole document, I am sure it mentions that somewhere

Comment: Yeah, it's a general comment in section 4.3.4: "... All values MUST be stored in little-endian byte order unless otherwise specified in this document for a specific data element."